# Locale has no effect

Tags: 13.10, thunderbird, locale

I've edited `/etc/default/locale` to look like this:

```
LANG="en_CA.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_CA:en"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `en_DK` did nothing, because my Thunderbird date/times still look like 14-03-03 04:02 PM. So how do I get this to kick in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/default/locale` contains the system default settings, but if you have user level settings e.g. in `~/.pam_environment` they take precedence.

If you want to use en_DK.UTF-8 for a single locale category, I'd recommend that you edit your `~/.profile` file and add:

```
export LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Just edited `~/.pam_environment` instead.

Comment: @Reinderien: Well, that works too. Just remember that if you use Language Support to change the regional formats for some reason, you'll need to redo it.